# Storing value of one HTML page and storing in database and using it again in another HTML page

Tags: html, database, object

I want to know that as I am using a number of HTML pages with different JavaScript codes and in one HTML page it shows total sales (the value will be entered by user) column which is multiplied by price (value will be entered by user) which will show the answer in next column. I want to use that answer in my next HTML page automatically or just by clicking one button by user.

How can I do that? Do I have to link .js file in script tag in another HTM page or I have to store the answer in database if I have to store. And if I have store answer in database how can I use it in another HTML page?

Comment: I am using localStorage.setItem("ID",ID); to store the data                                                    and ID= Number(localStorage.getItem("ID")); to get the stored value in another function

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store data into a database. you need to use PHP and SQL. I recommend PDO and mysql.
Here is a w3c page on how to setup a connection:

[connection to MYSQL with PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)